# ID of ocean related cartoon shorts

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Can you help me identify a cartoon  shorts collection with the ocean as the main theme?

I only remember some of the stories. It would be mainly western cartoon style but from time to time a 3D animation would appear. Not sure about what audience it was aimed to.

It was in English, and i think I saw it on a VHS around 2001-2006, but it could be older.

Here is a list of some fragments of the stories i remember:

- mechanical dolphins or somethig related to dolphins (this used 3D for the dolphins swimming)
- a strange green light makes boats dissapear in the sea
- an island where people go mad
- refugees in a cabin during a snowstorm. Simultaneosly a giant villain combats 2 heroes (in 3d animation)

Comment: Pirates of Dark Water ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[The Real Adventures of Jonny Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Real_Adventures_of_Jonny_Quest)*** (1996-1997).

> A continuation of the *Jonny Quest* (1964) series and *The New Adventures of Jonny Quest* (1986) series, it features teenage adventurers Jonny Quest, Hadji Singh, and Jessie Bannon as they accompany Dr. Benton Quest and bodyguard Race Bannon to investigate strange phenomena, legends, and mysteries in exotic locales. Action also takes place in the virtual realm of QuestWorld, a three-dimensional cyberspace domain rendered with computer animation.